# Save data with 3 relations eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to save data with eloquent relationship.

I have following three tables: User Table, Category Table and Post Table.

Post Table

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('heading');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

Relations:

Category:

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

Post:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

User:

```
public function posts($category) {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

My Problem is that, how can I save post just by passing the Heading in create function. I want to use the relationship. As an example I want to use this kind of code:

```
$data = ['heading' => $heading];
$user->posts()->category()->create($data);
```

**Is this possible to do this kind of stuff ?**

Or any another simple way to achieve this.

**EDIT**

I need to create post by using this kind of relationship.

As per the process:

- user will fill up the form from which I will get the data along with
  the category id.
- Now I need to create data for that user related with the given category id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because after you call `posts()` method you won't get to the model's relation (only the query builder) so you will not access `category()` relation method. It's because `posts` are *one-to-many* relation and you don';t know exacly which record you refer to create data.

**EDIT**
If you want to create new `post` entry the the best way to sole this is:

```
$data = ['heading' => $heading, 'category_id' => $putHereCategoryId];
$user->posts()->create($data);
```

You'll need to obtain somehow the id of the desire category for the new post's entry.

Comment: Actually I need to create the post not category. User will submit the form of post from where I will get the post data and category id

Comment: Is it possible to save post by using category object? I do not want to send category id in the data array. I want to send only `heading` in `data`

Comment: But how? Where do you have information about the category if the `Post` object does not exists jet? :) You have to pass it somehow... How application can know which category you pick for the post?